# Average surface area of the outer portion of a human skull

Tags: measurement, human

I tried Google. I tried Bing. People don't seem to measure the surface areas of skulls much. I was only curious before. Now I need to know. I don't really wants to know about the face of the human skull, just the top, sides, and back "flat" portion of the skull. What is the surface area of this?

Comment: Welcome to BiologyStackExchange. Sometimes you have to search through primary sources (e.g. research articles), for example using [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=cranium+surface+area): [Sholts, S.B. et al. _Variation in the Measurement of Cranial Volume and Surface Area Using 3D Laser Scanning Technology_ (2010)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1556-4029.2010.01380.x)

Comment: your gonna have to get the linear measurements and do the math yourself, the skull is such a complex shape, surface area is not a useful measure so it is not recorded much and your guidelines are too vague for a meaningful estimation. .that or find a good 3d model and extract the data.